# Function returns null even though the data does exist in the DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to show a page with content from the database through slugs in Laravel, this works except for one instance. When I'm trying to get the detailed pages in our knowledge base, I keep getting a `404`, but when checking the database I can see the data with the right slug, id and everything.

- The url consists of: `://site.com/kennisbank/{knowledge}/{knowledge_sub}`
- `kennisbank` = knowledgebase
- `{knowledge}` = slug for the "category"
- `{knowledge_sub}` = slug for the "post"/detailed knowledge page

I tried `firstorFail()`, `findorFail()`, `where()` and `where()->get()` with a `foreach`, but none work. The function I'm using to get the data:

```
public function knowledge_single(Knowledge_Post $knowledge_post){
    dd($knowledge_post->id);
    $knowledges = Knowledge_Post::where('id', $knowledge_post->id)->firstorFail();

    return view('knowledge.details', compact('knowledges'));
}
```

I included the dd since it even gives `404` on that. The view itself:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row paper" style="min-height: 200px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                    <div class="collection o__ltr" style="display: flex;">
                        <div class="collection_meta col-md-10" dir="ltr">
                            <h1 class="t__h3 c__primary" style="margin: -5px 0 2px; font-size: 25px;">{{$knowledges->knowledge_sub_title}}</h1>
                            <br />
                            <p class="paper__preview">{!!$knowledges->knowledge_sub_content !!}</p>
                            <div class="avatar">
                                <div class="avatar__photo avatars__images o__ltr">
                                    <img id="image" src="{{asset('/img/avatars/')}}/{!! str_replace(' ', '', $knowledges->username) !!}avatar.jpg" alt="{{$knowledges->username}}" class="avatar__image">
                                </div>
                                <div class="avatar__info_sub">
                                    <div>
                                        Geschreven door <span class="c__darker">{{$knowledges->username}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/kennisbank/{knowledge}/{knowledge_sub}', ['as' => 'Kennisbank', 'uses' => 'KnowledgeController@knowledge_single']);
```

I expect the page to show with the right content.

Comment: I think that if you change your route var from `knowledge_sub` to `knowledge_post` it should work

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\KnowledgeController::knowledge_single() must be an instance of App\Knowledge_Post, string given.

This is the error I'm getting now

Comment: You shoudl follow the advice of @Ruub the route parameter name should match the injected variable name for the implicit model binding to work, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: I've changed `knowledge_sub` to `knowledge_post`, now I'm getting the error I just posted in the comments.

Comment: This is another question @SpookyCode, we need the revelant code to help you

Comment: Fixed it!The error was because I'm using `knowledge` in my route, but didn't define it in my function. Had to use `Knowledge $knowledge, Knowledge_Post $knowledge_post` Thank you!!

Comment: You should write an answer @SpookyCode

Answer (score 1):

It's returning 404 because you've typehinted the `Knowledge_Post` so it's using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding), which is probably not configured properly (either the route or the model, or a custom defined binding is required). Either fix the route model binding or disable it by removing the typehint and/or argument entirely.

Comment: The model has getRouteKeyName(){ return 'slug'; }

Comment: This comment should be part of the code posted in the question